# Clementine crashes immediately after starting it

Tags: 20.04, lubuntu, hp, clementine

I've used clementine on my Lubuntu 20.04 system for a while now and it's worked fine ... until yesterday when it refused to start.

I originally tried to open it from the Application Launcher and it showed an empty dialog box with the title **Clementine Error** before closing immediately.

I tried opening it from the terminal and I got the same result plus this:

```
nonso@HPEnvy:~$ clementine
__logging_message__22:14:52.110 WARN  unknown                          QSqlQuery::prepare: database not open
22:14:52.110 ERROR Database:595                     db error:  QSqlError("", "Unable to fetch row", "No query")
22:14:52.110 ERROR Database:596                     faulty query:  ""
22:14:52.110 ERROR Database:597                     bound values:  QMap()
__logging_message__22:14:52.111 WARN  unknown                          QSqlDatabasePrivate::database: unable to open database: "unable to open database file Error opening database"
__logging_message__22:14:52.111 WARN  unknown                          QSqlDatabasePrivate::removeDatabase: connection '1_thread_94257494135936' is still in use, all queries will cease to work.
__logging_message__22:14:52.111 WARN  unknown                          QSqlDatabasePrivate::addDatabase: duplicate connection name '1_thread_94257494135936', old connection removed.
__logging_message__22:14:52.111 WARN  unknown                          QSqlQuery::prepare: database not open
22:14:52.111 ERROR Database:595                     db error:  QSqlError("", "Unable to fetch row", "No query")
22:14:52.111 ERROR Database:596                     faulty query:  ""
22:14:52.111 ERROR Database:597                     bound values:  QMap()
__logging_message__22:14:52.113 WARN  unknown                          QSqlDatabasePrivate::database: unable to open database: "unable to open database file Error opening database"
__logging_message__22:14:52.113 WARN  unknown                          QSqlDatabasePrivate::removeDatabase: connection '1_thread_94257494135936' is still in use, all queries will cease to work.
__logging_message__22:14:52.113 WARN  unknown                          QSqlDatabasePrivate::addDatabase: duplicate connection name '1_thread_94257494135936', old connection removed.
__logging_message__22:14:52.265 WARN  unknown                          QSqlDatabasePrivate::database: unable to open database: "unable to open database file Error opening database"
__logging_message__22:14:52.265 WARN  unknown                          QSqlDatabasePrivate::removeDatabase: connection '1_thread_94257490955296' is still in use, all queries will cease to work.
__logging_message__22:14:52.265 WARN  unknown                          QSqlDatabasePrivate::addDatabase: duplicate connection name '1_thread_94257490955296', old connection removed.
__logging_message__22:14:52.353 WARN  unknown                          QSqlQuery::prepare: database not open
22:14:52.353 ERROR Database:595                     db error:  QSqlError("", "Unable to fetch row", "No query")
22:14:52.353 ERROR Database:596                     faulty query:  ""
22:14:52.353 ERROR Database:597                     bound values:  QMap()
__logging_message__22:14:52.353 WARN  unknown                          QSqlDatabasePrivate::database: unable to open database: "unable to open database file Error opening database"
__logging_message__22:14:52.354 WARN  unknown                          QSqlDatabasePrivate::removeDatabase: connection '1_thread_94257490955296' is still in use, all queries will cease to work.
__logging_message__22:14:52.354 WARN  unknown                          QSqlDatabasePrivate::addDatabase: duplicate connection name '1_thread_94257490955296', old connection removed.
__logging_message__22:14:52.354 WARN  unknown                          QSqlQuery::prepare: database not open
22:14:52.354 ERROR Database:595                     db error:  QSqlError("", "Unable to fetch row", "No query")
22:14:52.354 ERROR Database:596                     faulty query:  ""
22:14:52.354 ERROR Database:597                     bound values:  QMap()
__logging_message__22:14:52.378 WARN  unknown                          QSqlDatabasePrivate::database: unable to open database: "unable to open database file Error opening database"
__logging_message__22:14:52.378 WARN  unknown                          QSqlDatabasePrivate::removeDatabase: connection '1_thread_94257490955296' is still in use, all queries will cease to work.
__logging_message__22:14:52.378 WARN  unknown                          QSqlDatabasePrivate::addDatabase: duplicate connection name '1_thread_94257490955296', old connection removed.
__logging_message__22:14:52.379 WARN  unknown                          QSqlQuery::prepare: database not open
22:14:52.379 ERROR Database:595                     db error:  QSqlError("", "Unable to fetch row", "No query")
22:14:52.379 ERROR Database:596                     faulty query:  ""
22:14:52.379 ERROR Database:597                     bound values:  QMap()
__logging_message__22:14:52.385 WARN  unknown                          QSqlDatabasePrivate::database: unable to open database: "unable to open database file Error opening database"
__logging_message__22:14:52.385 WARN  unknown                          QSqlDatabasePrivate::removeDatabase: connection '1_thread_94257494135936' is still in use, all queries will cease to work.
__logging_message__22:14:52.385 WARN  unknown                          QSqlDatabasePrivate::addDatabase: duplicate connection name '1_thread_94257494135936', old connection removed.
__logging_message__22:14:52.385 WARN  unknown                          QSqlQuery::prepare: database not open
22:14:52.386 ERROR Database:595                     db error:  QSqlError("", "Unable to fetch row", "No query")
22:14:52.386 ERROR Database:596                     faulty query:  ""
22:14:52.386 ERROR Database:597                     bound values:  QMap()
__logging_message__22:14:52.390 WARN  unknown                          QSqlDatabasePrivate::database: unable to open database: "unable to open database file Error opening database"
__logging_message__22:14:52.390 WARN  unknown                          QSqlDatabasePrivate::removeDatabase: connection '1_thread_94257494135936' is still in use, all queries will cease to work.
__logging_message__22:14:52.390 WARN  unknown                          QSqlDatabasePrivate::addDatabase: duplicate connection name '1_thread_94257494135936', old connection removed.
__logging_message__22:14:52.390 WARN  unknown                          QSqlQuery::prepare: database not open
22:14:52.390 ERROR Database:595                     db error:  QSqlError("", "Unable to fetch row", "No query")
22:14:52.390 ERROR Database:596                     faulty query:  ""
22:14:52.390 ERROR Database:597                     bound values:  QMap()
__logging_message__22:14:52.418 WARN  unknown                          QSqlDatabasePrivate::database: unable to open database: "unable to open database file Error opening database"
__logging_message__22:14:52.418 WARN  unknown                          QSqlDatabasePrivate::removeDatabase: connection '1_thread_94257494135936' is still in use, all queries will cease to work.
__logging_message__22:14:52.418 WARN  unknown                          QSqlDatabasePrivate::addDatabase: duplicate connection name '1_thread_94257494135936', old connection removed.
__logging_message__22:14:52.418 WARN  unknown                          QSqlQuery::prepare: database not open
22:14:52.418 ERROR Database:595                     db error:  QSqlError("", "Unable to fetch row", "No query")
22:14:52.418 ERROR Database:596                     faulty query:  ""
22:14:52.418 ERROR Database:597                     bound values:  QMap()
__logging_message__22:14:52.429 WARN  unknown                          QSqlQuery::prepare: database not open
22:14:52.429 ERROR Database:595                     db error:  QSqlError("", "Unable to fetch row", "No query")
22:14:52.429 ERROR Database:596                     faulty query:  ""
22:14:52.429 ERROR Database:597                     bound values:  QMap()
__logging_message__22:14:52.436 WARN  unknown                          QSqlDatabasePrivate::database: unable to open database: "unable to open database file Error opening database"
__logging_message__22:14:52.436 WARN  unknown                          QSqlDatabasePrivate::removeDatabase: connection '1_thread_94257490955296' is still in use, all queries will cease to work.
__logging_message__22:14:52.436 WARN  unknown                          QSqlDatabasePrivate::addDatabase: duplicate connection name '1_thread_94257490955296', old connection removed.
__logging_message__22:14:52.437 WARN  unknown                          QSqlQuery::exec: database not open
22:14:52.437 ERROR Database:595                     db error:  QSqlError("", "Unable to fetch row", "No query")
22:14:52.437 ERROR Database:596                     faulty query:  "DELETE FROM subsonic_songs"
22:14:52.437 ERROR Database:597                     bound values:  QMap()
__logging_message__22:14:52.442 WARN  unknown                          QSqlDatabasePrivate::database: unable to open database: "unable to open database file Error opening database"
__logging_message__22:14:52.442 WARN  unknown                          QSqlDatabasePrivate::removeDatabase: connection '1_thread_94257494135936' is still in use, all queries will cease to work.
__logging_message__22:14:52.442 WARN  unknown                          QSqlDatabasePrivate::addDatabase: duplicate connection name '1_thread_94257494135936', old connection removed.
__logging_message__22:14:52.442 WARN  unknown                          QSqlQuery::prepare: database not open
22:14:52.442 ERROR Database:595                     db error:  QSqlError("", "Unable to fetch row", "No query")
22:14:52.442 ERROR Database:596                     faulty query:  ""
22:14:52.442 ERROR Database:597                     bound values:  QMap()
__logging_message__22:14:52.448 WARN  unknown                          QSqlDatabasePrivate::database: unable to open database: "unable to open database file Error opening database"
__logging_message__22:14:52.448 WARN  unknown                          QSqlDatabasePrivate::removeDatabase: connection '1_thread_94257494135936' is still in use, all queries will cease to work.
__logging_message__22:14:52.448 WARN  unknown                          QSqlDatabasePrivate::addDatabase: duplicate connection name '1_thread_94257494135936', old connection removed.
__logging_message__22:14:52.449 WARN  unknown                          QSqlQuery::prepare: database not open
22:14:52.449 ERROR Database:595                     db error:  QSqlError("", "Unable to fetch row", "No query")
22:14:52.449 ERROR Database:596                     faulty query:  ""
22:14:52.449 ERROR Database:597                     bound values:  QMap()
__logging_message__22:14:52.455 WARN  unknown                          QSqlDatabasePrivate::database: unable to open database: "unable to open database file Error opening database"
__logging_message__22:14:52.455 WARN  unknown                          QSqlDatabasePrivate::removeDatabase: connection '1_thread_94257494135936' is still in use, all queries will cease to work.
__logging_message__22:14:52.455 WARN  unknown                          QSqlDatabasePrivate::addDatabase: duplicate connection name '1_thread_94257494135936', old connection removed.
__logging_message__22:14:52.455 WARN  unknown                          QSqlQuery::prepare: database not open
22:14:52.455 ERROR Database:595                     db error:  QSqlError("", "Unable to fetch row", "No query")
22:14:52.455 ERROR Database:596                     faulty query:  ""
22:14:52.455 ERROR Database:597                     bound values:  QMap()
__logging_message__22:14:52.460 WARN  unknown                          QSqlDatabasePrivate::database: unable to open database: "unable to open database file Error opening database"
__logging_message__22:14:52.460 WARN  unknown                          QSqlDatabasePrivate::removeDatabase: connection '1_thread_94257494135936' is still in use, all queries will cease to work.
__logging_message__22:14:52.460 WARN  unknown                          QSqlDatabasePrivate::addDatabase: duplicate connection name '1_thread_94257494135936', old connection removed.
__logging_message__22:14:52.460 WARN  unknown                          QSqlQuery::prepare: database not open
22:14:52.460 ERROR Database:595                     db error:  QSqlError("", "Unable to fetch row", "No query")
22:14:52.460 ERROR Database:596                     faulty query:  ""
22:14:52.460 ERROR Database:597                     bound values:  QMap()
__logging_message__22:14:52.461 WARN  unknown                          libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
__logging_message__22:14:52.466 WARN  unknown                          QSqlDatabasePrivate::database: unable to open database: "unable to open database file Error opening database"
__logging_message__22:14:52.466 WARN  unknown                          QSqlDatabasePrivate::removeDatabase: connection '1_thread_94257494135936' is still in use, all queries will cease to work.
__logging_message__22:14:52.466 WARN  unknown                          QSqlDatabasePrivate::addDatabase: duplicate connection name '1_thread_94257494135936', old connection removed.
__logging_message__22:14:52.466 WARN  unknown                          QSqlQuery::prepare: database not open
22:14:52.466 ERROR Database:595                     db error:  QSqlError("", "Unable to fetch row", "No query")
22:14:52.466 ERROR Database:596                     faulty query:  ""
22:14:52.466 ERROR Database:597                     bound values:  QMap()
__logging_message__22:14:52.468 WARN  unknown                          QSqlQuery::prepare: database not open
22:14:52.468 ERROR Database:595                     db error:  QSqlError("", "Unable to fetch row", "No query")
22:14:52.468 ERROR Database:596                     faulty query:  ""
22:14:52.468 ERROR Database:597                     bound values:  QMap()
__logging_message__22:14:52.482 WARN  unknown                          QSqlDatabasePrivate::database: unable to open database: "unable to open database file Error opening database"
__logging_message__22:14:52.482 WARN  unknown                          QSqlDatabasePrivate::removeDatabase: connection '1_thread_94257490955296' is still in use, all queries will cease to work.
__logging_message__22:14:52.482 WARN  unknown                          QSqlDatabasePrivate::addDatabase: duplicate connection name '1_thread_94257490955296', old connection removed.
__logging_message__22:14:52.483 WARN  unknown                          QSqlQuery::prepare: database not open
22:14:52.483 ERROR Database:595                     db error:  QSqlError("", "Unable to fetch row", "No query")
22:14:52.483 ERROR Database:596                     faulty query:  ""
22:14:52.483 ERROR Database:597                     bound values:  QMap()
__logging_message__22:14:52.509 WARN  unknown                          QSqlDatabasePrivate::database: unable to open database: "unable to open database file Error opening database"
__logging_message__22:14:52.509 WARN  unknown                          QSqlDatabasePrivate::removeDatabase: connection '1_thread_94257494223968' is still in use, all queries will cease to work.
__logging_message__22:14:52.509 WARN  unknown                          QSqlDatabasePrivate::addDatabase: duplicate connection name '1_thread_94257494223968', old connection removed.
__logging_message__22:14:52.509 WARN  unknown                          QSqlQuery::prepare: database not open
22:14:52.509 ERROR Database:595                     db error:  QSqlError("", "Unable to fetch row", "No query")
22:14:52.509 ERROR Database:596                     faulty query:  ""
22:14:52.509 ERROR Database:597                     bound values:  QMap()
__logging_message__22:14:52.509 WARN  unknown                          QSqlDatabasePrivate::database: unable to open database: "unable to open database file Error opening database"
__logging_message__22:14:52.509 WARN  unknown                          QSqlDatabasePrivate::removeDatabase: connection '1_thread_94257494223968' is still in use, all queries will cease to work.
__logging_message__22:14:52.509 WARN  unknown                          QSqlDatabasePrivate::addDatabase: duplicate connection name '1_thread_94257494223968', old connection removed.
__logging_message__22:14:52.509 WARN  unknown                          QSqlQuery::prepare: database not open
22:14:52.509 ERROR Database:595                     db error:  QSqlError("", "Unable to fetch row", "No query")
22:14:52.509 ERROR Database:596                     faulty query:  ""
22:14:52.509 ERROR Database:597                     bound values:  QMap()
__logging_message__22:14:52.543 WARN  unknown                          QSqlDatabasePrivate::database: unable to open database: "unable to open database file Error opening database"
__logging_message__22:14:52.543 WARN  unknown                          QSqlDatabasePrivate::removeDatabase: connection '1_thread_94257490955296' is still in use, all queries will cease to work.
__logging_message__22:14:52.543 WARN  unknown                          QSqlDatabasePrivate::addDatabase: duplicate connection name '1_thread_94257490955296', old connection removed.
__logging_message__22:14:52.543 WARN  unknown                          QSqlQuery::prepare: database not open
22:14:52.543 ERROR Database:595                     db error:  QSqlError("", "Unable to fetch row", "No query")
22:14:52.543 ERROR Database:596                     faulty query:  ""
22:14:52.543 ERROR Database:597                     bound values:  QMap()
__logging_message__22:14:52.544 WARN  unknown                          QSqlDatabasePrivate::database: unable to open database: "unable to open database file Error opening database"
__logging_message__22:14:52.544 WARN  unknown                          QSqlDatabasePrivate::removeDatabase: connection '1_thread_94257490955296' is still in use, all queries will cease to work.
__logging_message__22:14:52.544 WARN  unknown                          QSqlDatabasePrivate::addDatabase: duplicate connection name '1_thread_94257490955296', old connection removed.
__logging_message__22:14:52.544 WARN  unknown                          QSqlQuery::prepare: database not open
22:14:52.544 ERROR Database:595                     db error:  QSqlError("", "Unable to fetch row", "No query")
22:14:52.544 ERROR Database:596                     faulty query:  ""
22:14:52.544 ERROR Database:597                     bound values:  QMap()
__logging_message__22:14:52.544 ERROR unknown                          Couldn't create playlist
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I saw some answers online that talked about deleting a `Clementine.conf` file but I can't find it and I even tried using mlocate but I still couldn't find it.
I removed Clementine, reinstalled it and it still didn't work.
Every other solution I saw were for (way) older versions of Ubuntu.

Here are my system stats:

```
OS: Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS x86_64 
Host: HP ENVY Notebook
Kernel: 5.13.0-35-generic 
Uptime: 3 hours, 7 mins 
Packages: 1906 (dpkg), 33 (brew), 8 (snap) 
Shell: bash 5.0.17 
Resolution: 1366x768 
DE: LXQt 
WM: Openbox 
Terminal: qterminal 
CPU: Intel i5-7200U (4) @ 3.100GHz 
GPU: Intel HD Graphics 620 
Memory: 3740MiB / 7835MiB
```

Comment: I'm not using *focal* or 20.04, but my `Clementine.conf` file is located in `~/.config/Clementine/` .   Personally I'd test the deletion theory out on a testbox first (*install to a VM for example*) to ensure it won't do anything bad (*I have no idea what it'll do as I've done it or looked at it*), I can look later but not currently sorry though I'll use *jammy* as it's what we're [Lubuntu team] QA-testing currently..

Comment: Thanks. I've checked that directory but it's not there. I use [Strawberry](https://www.strawberrymusicplayer.org/) now.